# Does comparing c++ strings via default copy constructor impact performance and why?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to understand the performance implication of `std::string` copy constructor when used for string comparison. Here is the code I wrote for test

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void function1(std::string& v1)
{
    std::string result;
    std::string v2 = v1;
    for(int i = 0; i<v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(v1[i] == v2[i])
        {
            result="function1: Elements are the same for " + std::to_string(i) + " times";
        }
    }
    std::cout<<result<<'\n';
}

void function2(std::string& v1)
{
    std::string result;
    std::string v2 = v1;
    for(int i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if(std::string(v1[i],1) == std::string(v2[i],1))
        {
            result="function2: Elements are the same for " + std::to_string(i) + " times";
        }
    }
    std::cout<<result<<'\n';
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
  string longString = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
  "Vestibulum at velit in erat hendrerit venenatis at nec lorem. Etiam ante justo, "
  "finibus vel erat ut, porttitor vestibulum diam. Aenean a mauris id ante porta pulvinar. "
  "Mauris est est, lacinia a placerat ut, eleifend quis nisl. Ut posuere ultrices interdum. "
  "Morbi tristique elit quis nibh pharetra, vel aliquam libero iaculis. Suspendisse tempus,"
  "orci non volutpat hendrerit, metus ex feugiat risus, id vehicula risus velit eu elit. "
  "Mauris iaculis vehicula turpis, vitae tempor leo elementum id. Maecenas rhoncus ex quis" 
  "nulla tincidunt consectetur. Sed sit amet lectus tempor, egestas libero quis, viverra massa. C++";

  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  function1(longString);
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "------------------    " << std::endl;
  begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  function2(longString);
  end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[µs]" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds> (end - begin).count() << "[ns]" << std::endl;
}
```

On my local machine I am getting the following result:

```
function1: Elements are the same for 670 times
Time difference = 395[µs]
Time difference = 395565[ns]
------------------    
function2: Elements are the same for 670 times
Time difference = 475[µs]
Time difference = 475549[ns]
```

Why is there a time difference? Does the `std::string` copy constructor contribute to this performance difference and why ?

Comment: You might want to profile the code you show (built with optimization enabled, never benchmark or profile without optimizations), because I suspect a large part of the time of those functions will be the construction of the string for `result`.

Comment: `v1[i] == v2[i]` compares the elements of the strings (`char`) and `std::string(v1[i],1) == std::string(v2[i],1)` creates two new strings and then compares those strings. The second one does things it does not need to do, and those things take more than 0 amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I remove the construction of result and seem to get a different result. That is with result commented out, function1 seem to be slower 
 Time difference = 126[µs]
Time difference = 126176[ns]
------------------    

Time difference = 91[µs]
Time difference = 91760[ns]

Comment: why would you copy strings when you actually want to compare them?

Comment: Your test is invalid since it measures lots of side effects. Also you have to specify test environment, compiler and compiler options. Chosen comparison method is also an overkill (note `std::string` provides respective methods).

Comment: both versions unnecessarily recompute `result` in every iteration. You only need it once

Comment: Your question is "why copying and then comparing is slower than comparing"? Maybe because you copy things? :) Nevertheless, you need to show the compilation command so that we can say more. Another point: shouldn't you use probably use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock instead of steady clock?

Comment: Isn't this time difference below clocks resolution time?

Answer (score 0):

In function2, you build new strings every time you want to compare elements, which is costly.

An alternative in that case could be to use a `string_view`, you can see the modification [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_MCN97), but it's still overkill since you just want to compare two objects. No need for intermediate objects in this case.

I understand you are probably trying out things, but it's simpler to directly compare two strings with the '==' operator. It's more legible and faster. See [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/APm845) for a comparison of that method with your previous two functions.

Answer (score 0):

In the first function you are comparing a char to char which is very cheap

But in the second one you are constructing two strings each iteration with one char then comparing them and the get destructed at the end of the iteration , however, the there is no very much difference in performance because this allocation won't allocate memory due to SSO optimization and the compiler can deduce the string length at compile time but it can't make it as performant as the first function